# Facebook account kit - web - improve workflow?

Tags: account-kit

I've implemented the Facebook account kit as an auth method for my web app the the workflow is pretty clunky. The email auth workflow ends up with the user opening a new tab, clicking login and ending up on the same, blank page.

There doesn't seem to be any way to close the tab after auth, or redirect to the app. I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to make this more seamless. Any way to redirect the user, or close the page, or add text that told the user what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a redirect URL that can be used in Account Kit web email flow. This URL needs to also be added to the Account Kit app settings on developer.facebook.com. API Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/webjs/reference